# powercfg.exe in Linux

Tags: linux, power-management

Could someone translate these commands for linux?

```
powercfg.exe /setACvalueindex OVERLAY_SCHEME_MAX SUB_PROCESSOR PERFEPP 0
powercfg.exe /setACvalueindex SCHEME_BALANCED SUB_PROCESSOR PERFEPP 33
powercfg.exe /setACvalueindex OVERLAY_SCHEME_MIN SUB_PROCESSOR PERFEPP 60
```

I am having issues with CPU on a Lenovo X1 Carbon 6th (**with AC plugged**) being always pegged to 4Ghz, making the fan constantly spinning (in idle) and the only solutions in Lenovo forums are Windows commands.

Not the topic of this question but I tried to control CPU and FAN with the following programs:

- intel-undervolt (set CPU Cache to -100 mV)
- thinkfan

Also:

```
$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor
powersave
```

And CPU values in idle:

```
Cpu speed from cpuinfo 2111.00Mhz
cpuinfo might be wrong if cpufreq is enabled. To guess correctly try estimating via tsc
Linux's inbuilt cpu_khz code emulated now
True Frequency (without accounting Turbo) 2111 MHz
  CPU Multiplier 21x || Bus clock frequency (BCLK) 100.52 MHz

Socket [0] - [physical cores=4, logical cores=8, max online cores ever=4]
  TURBO ENABLED on 4 Cores, Hyper Threading ON
  Max Frequency without considering Turbo 2211.52 MHz (100.52 x [22])
  Max TURBO Multiplier (if Enabled) with 1/2/3/4 Cores is  42x/42x/39x/39x
  Real Current Frequency 3888.34 MHz [100.52 x 38.68] (Max of below)
        Core [core-id]  :Actual Freq (Mult.)      C0%   Halt(C1)%  C3 %   C6 %  Temp      VCore
        Core 1 [0]:       3876.97 (38.57x)      1.02    94.4       1    2.77    57      1.1874
        Core 2 [1]:       3873.57 (38.53x)         1    92.5       1    4.71    58      1.2014
        Core 3 [2]:       3879.58 (38.59x)      1.93    85.7       1    9.77    59      1.2114
        Core 4 [3]:       3888.34 (38.68x)      99.9       0       0       0    78      1.1807

C0 = Processor running without halting
C1 = Processor running with halts (States >C0 are power saver modes with cores idling)
C3 = Cores running with PLL turned off and core cache turned off
C6, C7 = Everything in C3 + core state saved to last level cache, C7 is deeper than C6
```

Thanks.

Comment: What are those commands supposed to be doing?

Comment: @muru: that changes the processor enerfy performance policy, and about the last parameter PERFEPP: this is the official explanation: "PerfEnergyPreference specifies the value to program in the energy performance preference register on systems that implement version 2 of the CPPC interface.", which I do not understand. Anyway, I think they just "solve" the fan problem limiting the CPU performance, which I finally did disabling intel_pstate and using instead acpi-cpufreq driver. The fan now stays quiet (the motherboard is faulty, though).